# Restricting attributes of a XSD element when within a different element than normal

Tags: xml, xsd

In my XSD file I have an alement 'row' of type 'rowType'.

When places within another element 'frozen', I would like to restrict the type of 'row' to a subset of 'rowType's allowable values.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [restriction](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_restriction.asp) and place it inside a new complex type derived from `rowType`.  Then add a row element to the `frozen` element which is a type of the new complex type.